# Content Download takes too much in chrome for Web App

Tags: java, angularjs, google-chrome

So I have been facing this problem for quite a while and I have researched everywhere I could to find a solution for this but to no avail.

The webpage that we are designing has some performance issues so I checked the network time and it seems 95% of the time is taken by content download. I have checked logs and everything is responding quickly, all the queries runs fast and all the functions completes without any issue. I dont seem to figure out why and where content download time is coming from.

On my local machine it takes milliseconds but on server it takes around 1 min for ~220 records.

[Screenshot of Network Tab on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4l40.png)

[Screenshot of same application on my local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBPhV.png)

[Request Headers on local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJCh3.png)

[Request Headers on Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrxql.png)

Please any suggestion I could try. This java Spring boot application ,database is postgres

Comment: 3.8 megabytes is kind of big.

Comment: Yeah I thought it is not that big since you know we have internet speed in gigabyte I thought 3.8mb will pe a piece of cake but it wasnt. I have applied gzip compression and it blazing fast :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally I figured out why there was so much difference of time taken for content download.

Basically when on localhost all the data is downloaded directly to the machine and processed so there is no need to download any content what so ever. But incase of server, the data is downloaded on the server and processed after processing this data needs to sent to client machine and that's where content download time kicks in.

I know it's so basic but I never knew what content download is?

Anyway I was able to get content download time to under 3 secs on server by enabling gzip compression.